# Bibliography not compiling

Tags: bibtex, compiling, natbib

I have a latex file for my dissertation wherein I `include` several chapters. Everthing (`\ref`, figures) compiles file **except** my bibliography.
Scouring the internet does me no help as this seems to be full of deadends. The error message from `bibtex` that I get is:

```
 bibtex Thesis_Final_ps_11142012a.aux 
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis_Final_ps_11142012a.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Applications.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: LiteratureReview.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Microgravity.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: modified-evolution-equation-11_08_2012.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ConstitutiveRelationship_05_17_2012a.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: MaximizingWavenumber_11082012.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Validation_ps.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Results_1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Contributions.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: mathfluid_3.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis_Final_ps_11142012a.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis_Final_ps_11142012a.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

My latex file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{MTU_Thesis_Style21}
%
%Stuff like names that I don't want to reveal on this forum
%
\include{Applications}                                       
\include{LiteratureReview}


%% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{/home/user/Research/Dissertation/Draft/unsrtnat}                 
\bibliography{/home/user/Research/Dissertation/Draft/dnaneet_MASTER}    

\end{document}

%% eof
```

My preamble (MTU_Thesis_Style21) has:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}    
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=small,labelsep=period,labelfont=bf}
% --------
\usepackage{lscape}         % allows for landscape tables and figures
\usepackage{paralist}       % enancements to list environment
\usepackage{array}          % enhancements to array and tabular environments
\usepackage[usenames]{color}    
\usepackage{url}            
\usepackage{longtable}      % multipage tables
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{setspace}       % easy single or doublespacing
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{rotate}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}       % for listing computer code such as matlab
\usepackage[bw]{mcode}      % for matlab code with listings package
\usepackage[square,comma,sort&compress]{natbib} % enhances bibtex citations
% \usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}       % \singlespacing, \onehalfspacing, \doublespacing, ...

%%%%%%%%uyser%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{changepage}
```

I can't seem to figure out whats going wrong.
When I try to bibtex my aux file without all these `\include` statements, things are fine!!!!

Why are most of my citations missing from my `aux` file? `:(` I am beginning to hate latex with a passion.

### Aux file:

```
\relax 
\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global \let \oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef \contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global \let \oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef \newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef \newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\let \contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let \newlabel\oldnewlabel}
\else
\global \let \hyper@last\relax 
\fi

\providecommand*\HyPL@Entry[1]{}
\HyPL@Entry{0<</S/r>>}
\HyPL@Entry{2<</S/r>>}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\hbox to\@tempdima {\hfil }Table of Contents}{iii}{chapter*.1}}
\citation{Krishnamoorthy1995a}
\citation{Krishnamoorthy1995a}
\citation{Krishnamoorthy1995a}
\citation{Oron2000b}
\citation{Oron2000b}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\hbox to\@tempdima {\hfil }List of Figures}{xiii}{chapter*.2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\hbox to\@tempdima {\hfil }List of Tables}{xiv}{chapter*.3}}
\@input{Applications.aux}
\HyPL@Entry{16<</S/D>>}
\@input{LiteratureReview.aux}
\@input{Microgravity.aux}
\@input{modified-evolution-equation-11_08_2012.aux}
\@input{ConstitutiveRelationship_05_17_2012a.aux}
\@input{MaximizingWavenumber_11082012.aux}
\@input{Validation_ps.aux}
\@input{Results_1.aux}
\@input{Contributions.aux}
\@input{mathfluid_3.aux}
```

### Causative of the error message

The error messages that `bibtex` gave me were as a result of two of the `.tex` files that I included using `\include`

```
%mathfluid.tex
\input{format_mathplots_3}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{}
\input{include_grphx_3}
\end{document}
%% eof
```

The above `mathfluid.tex` that I used in one of the `\include` called on another tex file via `\input{format_mathplots_3}`. This `format_math_plots.tex` was again, erroneously included in the main file. Somehow (I don't know why) bibtex didn't like that althoug this file didn't have any citations. It might be as a result of conflicting `aux` files but I am clueless about it.

Would anyone care to offer an explanation for this? `:)`

Comment: Is your MWE definitely *minimal*? :)

Comment: @cmhughes I don't know how much more I can condense my er... MWE... without omitting perhaps something important. sorry.... `:(`. The full file is several 100 lines long.

Comment: @drN when you look at the `.aux` file you can notice that there are not `\bibstyle{...}` and `\bibdata{...}` these are created by `\bibliographystyle{...}` and `\bibliography{...}`. This suggests that there there might be a premature `\end{document}` in the file `mathfluid_3.tex`.

Comment: Have you tried removing all auxiliary files and recompiling? If that also doesn't work, I'd try using `\includeonly` in combination with `\include` and temporarily leaving out file by file until (hopefully) the problem is solved. I suggest you remove all auxiliary files after a failure and before you start recompiling. If @Guido is right about the premature `\end{document}` you can chase it by putting an undefined command at different locations in your file. If compilation fails, it means the location must have been before LaTeX saw the `\end{document}`, otherwise it must have been after.

Comment: it's almost certainly not related to the biblio problem, but in the preamble shown, the line `\usepackage{subfig}` appears twice, and also `\usepackage{subfigure}`.  `subfig` replaces `subfigure` according to the author (`texdoc subfig`), so two of those lines should go, regardless.  `paralist` is also duplicated.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Yes. I might have uncovered what is wrong with this. I will make the edit soon and perhaps I could use some insight later.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thats a good catch! However, it turns out not to be the cause of my troubles. I have uncovered my problem and will make my edit to the question soon. Perhaps, you could throw some light on the issue since I lack the `latex` relevant jargon/language to explain what happened!

Comment: @drN -- *if* this is what you mean by "throw some light", i'm going to ask you to enter a new question, something like ``why shouldn't `\usepackage` entries be repeated in a file?'.  two reasons for this: a good explanation could be more lengthy than can be accommodated by a comment, and as a comment, it's likely to go unnoticed.  i've made a cursory search to see if that question has been asked before, and found nothing (though someone else may prove me wrong).  also, i don't like submitting questions just to answer them myself, so i think you should do it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Edit made.

Comment: Be careful: `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in an included file are definitely out of place.

Comment: The problem might not be with BibTeX, it just showed up there. I had same symptom -- I found no \bibdata command---while reading file VCAmain.aux
-- I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file VCAmain.aux
but the problem was actually a bad \ref{} command to an equation label: I had typoed \ref{\label{Chang_5.42}}
rather than \ref{Chang_5.42}
So check other possible ways your .aux files might be corrupted.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: @Jubobs Oooh! Interesting!

Answer (score 49):

The BibTeX log reports that the `aux` files does not contain `\bibstyle` and `\bibdata`. These two instructions are written in the `aux` file by the commands `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`. The two commands are present in the main file.  This suggests that one of the included files contains `\end{document}`. In this case, the `\end{document}` appears in  `mathfluid_3.tex` (or as the edit indicates in one of the files embedded in it).  `\end{document}`, typically, instructs the TeX compilers to terminates the compilation, and everything appering after it is ignored.

Comment: Crazy stuff. Still doesn't work